# one workflow for all libraries in a site

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, designer-workflow, document, access-rights

I have requirement, in which I have to make workflow to Shot an email and change rights of document based on a master list exist in the site itself.

Now the concern is I have to build a mechanism that whenever a new document library got added in the that site and any document added or updated with in it or any existing library. The workflow should trigger as per the process stated in the master list.

I have no experience with workflow but I am thinking to add Document Library named column in that master list and then read the master list on the trigger of workflow and then workflow will act accordingly

Now I have three queries here

1. Is it the right approach !!
2. How to trigger the workflow on add/update of document in any existing and new document library in the site
3. Can SharePoint Designer workflow change the right/permission of the document with the sub folders (any level) of a document library

FYI.. it on SharePoint Online

Answer (score 0):

1. Not fully.
2. You cannot do that, you will need an WF for each library.
3. DP Designer WF can change permission on item or folder.

You need to come up with approach how to add an wf to a library when new library is created. So you would need a master WF for site (probably running on schedule) that would add a new WF. I know there are some options with FLow to do that. In the past i made such solution on prem but it required custom server side code.

Comment: you mean to say the site workflow is able to create a new workflow for each new library !

Comment: Have look at this one https://sii.pl/blog/ms-flow-provisioning/